# Не отображает изображение background: url('images/AboutU.png') repeat-y center

Tags: html5, background, style, background-image

Не отображается картинка в header. Выводится только при условии, если дальше отдельно пропишу `<img src = "images/AboutU.png"`. Помогите найти причину сего затруднения

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum- 
scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body style="margin: 0;background: url('images/AboutUs.png') repeat-y center; background- 
size:contain">
    <header style="background: url('images/AboutU.png') repeat-x center;background-size:contain ;
border-top: solid #f2f9e7 12px;border-bottom: 15px solid #ffffff; ">
    </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Немного непонятно: зачем повторение по высоте в заголовке?

Answer (score 0):

Решается явным указанием ширины в заголовке.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum- 
scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <header style="height: 200px;background: url('images/AboutUs.png') repeat center;background-size:contain ;
border-top: solid #f2f9e7 12px;border-bottom: 15px solid #ffffff; ">
    </header>
    </body>
</html>
```